# creating generic file in generic folder using QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I created a generic folder by taking the name from DataTable:

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strdata = Datatable.Value("Column name", "Sheet")
fso.CreateFolder "C:\Documents and Settings\schoudar\Desktop\" & strdata
```

Till this I am successful but now I want to save a file in this folder and the folder name changes when I do no. of iterations. So I tried with `CaptureBitmap` file:

```
Browser("Browser").CaptureBitmap "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\ & strdata\filename.bmp"
```

But it is not working so please help me out.

Comment: -1 for describing the problem with the classic "It is not working" statement...

Answer (score 4):

What error are you getting?

Just a guess, fix the quotes and string appends:

```
Browser("Browser").CaptureBitmap "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\" & strdata & "\filename.bmp"
```